# Zen-Cart - Home link not working

Tags: php, installation, http-status-code-404, zen-cart

I have a problem with a zen cart installation.

When I try to click on "home" i get a 404 page... Does anybody know why or how to get it fixed?

if I go to http://derbycitycomputers.com/index.php, it works, but if I go to http://derbycitycomputers.com/index.php&zenid=51c08d176640b27169681077e5003edc
it does not...

any help on the reason why this might be?

Thx a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to do:

http://derbycitycomputers.com/index.php?zenid=51c08d176640b27169681077e5003edc

With a question mark in stead of an ampersand.

After the base url you always first have to use a question mark.

If you want to add more than 1 variable to the url use `&`

http://derbycitycomputers.com/index.php?zenid=51c08d176640b27169681077e5003edc&othervar=value